# How to show and retrieve image data from Apache Solr into an image in a webpage?

Tags: solr, backend

I was not able to retrieve binary image data from apache solr into images and that can be shown into website

Comment: Please provide a bit more data. Do you have a code snippet that you are using. 
please show what effort you have put already and any logs that you see.

Comment: Also knowing Solr, it is not the right place to be storing binary data. perhaps a little information on the use case would also help